# Store objects on the Flask object

Tags: flask

I need to store an object on my `flask.Flask` instance. The naive approach would be just assigning an attribute like this.

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.my_object = MyObject()
```

I'm planning on referencing it later in an application context like this:

```
flask.current_app.my_object
```

I doubt this method is thread save though. Is there a correct method to do this that is encouraged by Flask? If not, how would you safely implement the approach above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up with using the config object.

```
app.config['MY_OBJECT'] = MyObject()
```

You can reference it like this in a request.

```
current_app.config['MY_OBJECT']
```